# Reverse for 'createActivity' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['create_Activity/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

hope you are doing well!
I am having this error `Reverse for 'createActivity' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['create_Activity/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']`

it's working for createSousActivity but for createActivity it doesn't work.

this is my **urls.py**

```
path('create_Activity/<str:pk>/', views.createActivity, name="createActivity"),
path('update_Activity/<str:pk>/', views.UpdateActivity, name="updateActivity"),
path('delete_activity/<str:pk>/',views.DeleteActivity, name="deleteActivity"),

path('create_SousActivity/<str:pk>/', views.createSousActivity, name="createSousActivity"),
path('update_SousActivity/<str:pk>/', views.UpdateSousActivity, name="updateSousActivity"),
path('delete_Sousactivity/<str:pk>/',views.DeleteSousActivity, name="deleteSousActivity"),
```

this is my **views.py**

```
 def createActivity(request,pk):
   sdlc = SDLC_phase.objects.get(id=pk)

   form = ActivityForm(initial={'sdlc':sdlc})
   if request.method == "POST":
       form = ActivityForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect('/')

   context = {'form':form} 
   return render(request,'activitiestasks/Activity_form.html', context)
```

in my template

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-success  btn-sm btn-block" href="{% url 'createActivity' SDLCphases.id %}">Create Activity</a>
```

do anyone know this problem ?

Comment: how about `href="{% url 'createActivity' pk=SDLCphases.id %}"`

Comment: it gives the same error (

Comment: Why are you using `str` for `pk`?

Comment: `href="{% url 'createActivity' form.instance.pk %}` However please use `<int:pk>`, not `<str:pk>`, since that limits the patterns that will match to numerical ones.

Comment: it gives the same error again ( ... I don't know why it worked in 'createSousActivity'

Comment: I will try to use <int:pk>

Comment: Reverse for 'createActivity' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['create_Activity/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: Make sure you are testing with the trailing slash in your url, because that is the path you've set:  `path('create_Activity/<int:pk>/', views.createActivity, name="createActivity")`

Comment: could you show the working model? and more of template?

Comment: guys it worked for me finally but with <str:pk> , I really don't know why it worked , but I deleted the <int:pk> and then I refresh the link , after that it gives me an error like `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'createActivity' with arguments '(3,)' not f
ound. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['create_Activity/$']` and then in my urls.py I back to add <str:pk> finally it worked !!! that making me crazy like why it worked finally ?

Comment: but no still the same error after I felt happy ( , that's weird